# video content on iPhone Safari/UIWebView

Tags: iphone, video, uiwebview

In my application I have a UIWebView that is able to play Youtube videos normally, but I'd like to play some videos from a website other than Youtube.
If i try to play those videos in the iPhone Safari browser it opens in the same way that YouTube videos (fullscreen mode, showing the player), but that doesn't happen in the UIWebView inside my application.

As an example, consider the following URL: http://m.video.globo.com/#video.php?id=1174097 (don't forget to open it in the simulator)

I didn't have to download any plugin or application to play it. 
Both JavaScript and Plug-Ins options in the iPhone Settings are turned on.

Is there something wrong with my UIWebView? All I'm doing is loading the webpage using the "loadRequest" method from UIWebView class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If safari can play it, I don't see why your own UIWebView couldn't. Have you tried implementing `-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error` to see if an error is thrown and what it is?

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone has support for youtube videos, (hence the built in youtube player), other than that it supports only quicktime. There is no support for other formats: most sites use flash for video these days (inc youtube), but flash is not supported on the iPhone. I site embedding a youtube video will work, but one embedding a video hosted elsewhere will not (unless its quicktime)

Comment: Ok, you are right. But the problem wasn't with the iPhone UIWebView component, it was an website issue. I apologize for the confusion and appreciate your reply.